# Multiple else if statements

Tags: c, if-statement

i have this c code, regarding multiple if statements..
All statements are working nicely, except the final one..
It gets activated with other if statements and so ruins the result..
Any suggestions?

```
  for (i=0; i<(total); i++)
  {
    for (n=0; n<((total)/4); n++)
    {
        if (i==(0+(n*4)) && i<(total-5)&&(array[i]==0))
        {
            array[i]=1;
            i=n=500;                                     
            break;
        }
        else if ((i==(3+(n*4)))&&i<(total-5)&&(array[i]==0))
        {
            array[i]=1;
            i=n=500;
            break;
        }
        else if (i==(total)&&(array[i]==0))
        {
            array[i]=1;
            i=n=500;
            break;
        }
        else if (i==(total-1)&&(array[i]==0))
        {
            array[i]=1;
            i=n=500;
            break;
        }
        else
            printf("**Something**");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: there is no special `else if` in C. it's just a combination.

Comment: just replace your last `else` statement to and `else if` and you should be fine. **`c`** does not have it's implicit `else if` statement like other languages **(For eg: Python: `elif`)**.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the last 'else' and replace it with another 'else if'

```
for (i=0; i<(total); i++)
  {
    for (n=0; n<((total)/4); n++)
    {
        if (i==(0+(n*4)) && i<(total-5)&&(array[i]==0))
        {
            array[i]=1;
            i=n=500;                                     
            break;
        }
        else if ((i==(3+(n*4)))&&i<(total-5)&&(array[i]==0))
        {
            array[i]=1;
            i=n=500;
            break;
        }
        else if (i==(total)&&(array[i]==0))
        {
            array[i]=1;
            i=n=500;
            break;
        }
        else if (i==(total-1)&&(array[i]==0))
        {
            array[i]=1;
            i=n=500;
            break;
        }
        else if
            printf("**Something**");
    }
  }
}
```